# Python: Blocking Input to queue until condition

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I want to parallize an image read, evaluate and csv write process. Therefore my Idea is to create threads which loading Images and put them in a Queue (ImageQueue) which is then evaluated by multiple Processes, which picked the images from the ImageQueue and put the evaluated data to aanother Queue, where items get picked by writing threads. My only problem is that the image loading threads should only load more images if the queue is not already large enough (lets say 1000 images/items). Is there somekind of method which I can use to wait/block until enough items of the evaluate Processes picked Items form the ImageQueue? Somekind of Buffer?

So my threadReading would look like something like this:

```
def threadReading(dfInputData, imageQueue):
    for row in dfInputData.iterrows():
        start = time.time()
        image = fh.loadImage(row['imageName'])
        end = time.time()
        timingLoadImage = end - start
        #########################################################################
        #Here somekind of conition should block/wait until queue is small enough#
        #########################################################################
        imageQueue.put(row, image, timingLoadImage)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import queue

imageQueue = queue.Queue(maxsize=1000)
imageQueue.put(...)
```

it will block at `imageQueue.put(...)` until there is space in the queue again.

Comment: Note, the package is called `queue` in Python 3 and `Queue` in Python 2. You haven't specified which you are using.

Comment: I am using from multiprocessing import Queue in python 3. So Queue will wait to put things in it until the queue size is decreased by the process which uses the queue.get() function?

Comment: Ah, ok. You said that you wanted to "create threads" - which means multi-threading, which means `import queue`. Are you in fact doing multi-processing? Anyway, I'm pretty sure that `imageQueue = multiprocessing.Queue(maxsize=1000)` will also have the desired result

Comment: Yep, if you specifiy a maxsize it will block at the `put` call until the queue size has been reduced by another thread/process

Comment: oh yes, sry i was in vacation. Your solution was exactly what i needed! :)